# ASP.NET : Accepting dates of validation in MMYYYY format using Dropdown list USING VISUAL BASIC

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

Scenario. 
I have a dropdown list of Month(1-12) and Year (MMYYYY) format.
Start Date : Month(1-12) and Year (MMYYYY) format
End Date : Month(1-12) and Year (MMYYYY) format

If I would select the START DATE : 10/2018 (then the start date is valid)
*start date should not be more than 5 years based on the current year*
Then the "END DATE" should be End DATE : 10/2018 ( this is valid)

1. HOW CAN I ACCEPT THE START THE SHOULD NOT BE MORE THAN 5 YEARS FROM CURRENT DATE?
2. HOW CAN I ACCEPT THE END DATE THAT SHOULD NOT BE MORE THAN 5 YEARS FROM THE START DATE?

If achieved, another question:

1. HOW CAN I VALIDATE  Month - START DATE : 10/2018 END DATE : 10/2018
2. HOW CAN I VALIDATE Quarterly - START DATE : 01/2018 END DATE : 03/2018.
   *Quarterly are (Jan to Mar, Apr to Jun, July to Sep, Oct to Dec)
3. HOW CAN I VALIDATE Semi-annual - START DATE : 01/2018 END DATE : 06/2018 *SEMI - ANNUAL ARE ( JAN TO JUN, JULY TO DECEMBER)
4. HOW CAN I VALIDATE ANNUAL - START DATE: 01/2018 END DATE: 12/2018

ELSE INVALID

OUTPUT: VALID OR INVALID.

EXAMPLE:

```
INPUT-  START DATE: 10 2018 END DATE: 10 2018
OUTPUT: VALID ** THIS IS MONTHLY

INPUT-  START DATE: 10 2018 END DATE: 12 2018
OUTPUT: VALID ** THIS IS QUARTERLY

INPUT-  START DATE: 10 2018 END DATE: 03 2019
OUTPUT: VALID ** THIS IS SEMI-ANNUAL

INPUT-  START DATE: 01 2018 END DATE: 12 2018
OUTPUT: VALID ** THIS IS ANNUAL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter part of your question should probably be a new question on SO.  However, here goes...

> HOW CAN I ACCEPT THE START THE SHOULD NOT BE MORE THAN 5 YEARS FROM CURRENT DATE?
>
> HOW CAN I ACCEPT THE END DATE THAT SHOULD NOT BE MORE THAN 5 YEARS FROM THE START DATE?

You can create a date variable using the drop down list values, but each assume the first day of the month because a date needs a DAY part:

```
Dim dateStart As Date = New Date(ddl_dateStartYear.SelectedValue, ddl_dateStartMonth.SelectedValue, 1)
Dim dateEnd As Date = New Date(ddl_dateEndYear.SelectedValue, ddl_dateEndMonth.SelectedValue, 1)
' Today check
If dateEnd > DateTime.Now.AddYears(5) Then
    ' Invalid
End If
' Five year check
If dateStart.AddYears(5) > dateEnd Then
    ' Invalid
End If
```

> HOW CAN I VALIDATE Month - START DATE : 10/2018 END DATE : 10/2018

This is done automatically when the new date variable is created.

> 2)HOW CAN I VALIDATE Quarterly - START DATE : 01/2018 END DATE : 03/2018...

I'm afraid I don't understand the rest of your questions.  Perhaps delete these and place in a new question with more detail.